# Create a Twitter Bootstrap 'nav-tabs' menu without changing the URL - Is it possible?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am after a `nav-tab` that does not involve the URL changing but obviously the tabs change and display the relevant information.

I have an `angularjs` site but whenever the page refreshes it take the user back to the search page.  As the normal twitter bootstrap `nav-tabs` changes the URL I can not use this but it's something I want to do.

Questions are:

1. Does anyone know a way of doing this using the twitter bootstrap `nav-tabs`
2. If not, is there something else I can use which does the same

Below is cut of my code:

```
    <div class="row" data-ng-if="showcharts">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <!-- Nav tabs -->
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
            <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#productBreakdown" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><span class="tabHeadings">Product breakdown</span></a></li>
            <li role="presentation" style="border-right: 1px solid lightgray; border-left: 1px solid lightgray"><a href="#assetsBreakdown" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><span class="tabHeadings">Assets Breakdown</span></a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#nbBreakdown" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><span class="tabHeadings">New Business Breakdown</span></a></li>
        </ul>
        <!-- Tab panes -->
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="productBreakdown">
                <donutchart id="product-breakdown" data-options="productbreakdownchart"></donutchart>
            </div>
            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="assetsBreakdown">
                <donutchart id="asset-breakdown" data-options="assetbreakdownchart"></donutchart>
            </div>
            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="messages">TO BE ADDED</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Each tab will display an informational chart to the user.

Comment: I'm not seeing any url changes in the code you posted. The nav-tab works by adding and removing certain classes and attributes ( such as active and aria-expanded, respectively.) Can you be more specific as to which URL is/are changing? http://www.bootply.com/lpvCoTma3v

Comment: What bootstrap version are you using?

Comment: @Academia I am using Bootstrap 3

Comment: @Marcelo it appends '#productBreakdown' etc to my URL.  This is due to the `href` set in the `<a>` in the `<li>`.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

As you said in comments url changes due to the `href` attribute in the `<a>` tag. But you can leave `href` blank use `data-target="..."` attribute instead. So

```
<a href="#productBreakdown" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"></a>
```

will be

```
<a href data-target="#productBreakdown" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"></a>
```